# How to create a python executable with "./" without pyinstaller

Tags: python, linux, executable

I need to send my program to someone who will compile it using a makefile, and without pyinstaller or installing anything with pip3.

It needs to work on linux.

Is it possible ? (I can only find answers about pyinstaller and pyexe).

Comment: this is not possible, unless your python file doesn't use any libraries from `pip`, and the someone you're sending the file to already has the same version of python installed as you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a `file.py` executable using `./file.py` command, you first have to add the shebang as first line in the file: 
`#!/usr/bin/env python3` for python 3.x or `#!/usr/bin/env python2` if you are still using python 2.7

Next step is to change permissions of the file to make it executable.

You can do that by typing `chmod 744 file.py` in prompt

```
$ nano file.py
```

```
  GNU nano 2.0.6                             File: file.py                  

#!/usr/bin/env python3

name = input("Name: ")

print('Hello, {}'.format(name))
```

```
$ ./file.py
-bash: ./file.py: Permission denied
$ chmod 744 file.py
$ ./file.py
Name: Osa
Hello, Osa
```

Comment: This would still require pip3 for dependencies

Comment: @Ferrybig yes, assuming there are any